# Oracle - Do I have to drop and rebuild an index when I am doing a CTAS with rename

Tags: oracle, indexing, ctas

I have a very large table (greater than 5 BILLION records) instead of performing an update statement or even running a pl/sql bill collect/forall I am choosing to perform a CTAS with the update in the select. I am simply populating a date field with sysdate if it’s null.

After I create the NEW table I am renaming the OLD table and renaming the NEW table to the OLD tables original name.

I will compare record counts and other validations before dropping the OLD table.

My question is this, if there was an index on the date column for the OLD table do I have to drop that index and recreate it for it to work and work properly on the NEW table which has the OLD tables name now?

Comment: Additionally would the grants that were in place for the OLD table be intact and apply to the new table after the renaming process or would I have to recreate the grants for the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to create the index on the newly built table. The fact that the new table eventually gets the same name as the old table had does not in any way associate them within Oracle's dictionary. They are totally independent objects.

You will have to drop the old index from the old table first if you want the index on the new table to have the same name. Alternatively you could create the new index with a new name and then when doing the table name swap also rename the two indexes to swap their names. But when doing maintenance of this kind, there's usually no reason to keep the index on the old table since that table will continue to exist (if at all) only as a backup. So just drop the index on it so you can create an index with the same name on the new table. It also doesn't matter if you create the index on the new table before or after the table renames.

A table as large as you have should definitely be partitioned. A few notes about your index. In Exadata we almost never index date columns because Smart Scan eliminates the need to do so and date lookups are almost never high-frequency. In regular Oracle there still may be a need for them, but here are some considerations:

If your partitioning is on the *same* date column as the index, the index should be `LOCAL`. You can either build it all at once or you can create it initially as `UNUSABLE` and then rebuild each partition individually to minimize the temp space demands and optimize PX distribution. But if queries are asking for "lastest month" or "year 2022" and you partition on that date by month, you don't want that index to exist it all, it will only get in the way. Partition pruning will serve such queries much better. The only reason to index a date column that is also the partition key is if you have queries asking for a very tiny slice (e.g. an hour, or a day at most) within a much larger partition boundary. If that's not the case, leave the index off and allow partition pruning to effectively accomplish what the index was intended to.

If the index is on a *different* date column (not the partitioning key), you may still want to make it `LOCAL` to ease partition maintenance, as long as you don't have queries at high frequency (e.g. every few minutes) asking for very recent data without partition pruning (since every partition of the index would need a seek for each value lookup). If your queries are relatively low frequency, or ask for larger swaths of data, the benefits of local indexes far outweigh the performance benefit of a `GLOBAL` index.

Comment: Thank you this answered my specific question as well as gave me additional information I can use.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to create a partitioned table with the updated data and then use 'alter table exchange partition', so you would avoid problems with grants. Then you can rebuild all the indexes.

Simple example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/ynZG8lGh

```sql
-- our test table T:
create table t as
  select level a
        ,decode(mod(level,2),1,date'2020-01-01',sysdate) dt
  from dual
  connect by level<=1e4;
create index t_ix on t(dt);
alter table t add constraint t_pk primary key (a);

-- creating a temporary partitioned table with the updated data as we need:
create table t_new(
  a number primary key,
  dt date
)
  partition by range(a)
    (partition p1 values less than (maxvalue))
;
-- parallel direct insert from the old table:
insert/*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel(8) */ into t_new 
  select a, nvl(dt,sysdate) dt from t;

-- switching tables' data:
alter table t_new exchange partition p1 with table t;
-- checking indexes on T: as you can see all of them in in the UNUSABLE status:
select index_name,status from user_indexes where table_name='T';

-- rebuilding them in parallel and then switching them to noparallel:
begin
  for r in (
    select index_name 
    from user_indexes
    where table_name='T' 
    and status='UNUSABLE'
  )
  loop
    execute immediate 'alter index '||r.index_name||' rebuild parallel 8';
    execute immediate 'alter index '||r.index_name||' noparallel';
  end loop;
end;
/
--checking their statuses again: now they're valid:
select index_name,status from user_indexes where table_name='T';
```

Comment: Replacing grants isn't that big of a deal. Partition exchanges can be tricky, especially with hidden or unused columns, and you have to take care to ensure you don't miss any partitions. I've done plenty of both strategies... all in all I think CTAS/rename is the easier and definitely safer route.